# How does Python interface work (in Twisted)?

Tags: python, interface, twisted

I am following this [explanation](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/components.html), and I don't quite get how Python interpreter arrives at the following. In the first example, is Python seeing `@implementer(IAmericanSocket)` is not implemented by `UKSocket`, then it decides to make it a `AdaptToAmericanSocket` because that is the only implementation of `IAmericanSocket` with one argument? What if there is another class instance implementing `IAmericanSocket` with one argument? In the second example, why is `IAmericanSocket` not overriding `AmericanSocket`'s voltage method?

```
>>> IAmericanSocket(uk)
<__main__.AdaptToAmericanSocket instance at 0x1a5120>
>>> IAmericanSocket(am)
<__main__.AmericanSocket instance at 0x36bff0>
```

with the code below:

```
from zope.interface import Interface, implementer
from twisted.python import components

class IAmericanSocket(Interface):
    def voltage():
      """
      Return the voltage produced by this socket object, as an integer.
      """

@implementer(IAmericanSocket)
class AmericanSocket:
    def voltage(self):
        return 120

class UKSocket:
    def voltage(self):
        return 240

@implementer(IAmericanSocket)
class AdaptToAmericanSocket:
    def __init__(self, original):
        self.original = original

    def voltage(self):
        return self.original.voltage() / 2

components.registerAdapter(
    AdaptToAmericanSocket,
    UKSocket,
    IAmericanSocket)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the full documentation for zope.interface here: http://docs.zope.org/zope.interface/ - it may provide a more thorough introduction than Twisted's quick tutorial.

To answer your specific question, the `registerAdapter` call at the end there changes the behavior of calling `IAmericanSocket`.

When you call an `Interface`, it first checks to see if its argument *provides* itself.  Since the class `AmericanSocket` *implements* `IAmericanSocket`, instances of `AmericanSocket` *provide* `IAmericanSocket`.  This means that when you call `IAmercianSocket` with an argument of an `AmericanSocket` instance, you just get the instance back.

However, when the argument does not provide the interface already, the interface then searches for *adapters* which can convert something that the argument *does* provide to the target interface.  ("Searches for adapters" is a huge oversimplification, but Twisted's `registerAdapter` exists specifically to allow for this type of simplification.)

So when `IAmericanSocket` is called with an instance of a `UKSocket`, it finds a registered adapter from instances of `UKSocket`.  The adapter itself is a 1-argument callable that takes an argument of the type being adapted "from" (`UKSocket`) and returns a value of the type being adapted "to" (provider of `IAmericanSocket`).  `AdaptToAmericanSocket` is a class, but classes are themselves callable, and since its constructor takes a `UKSocket`, it fits the contract of thing-that-takes-1-argument-of-type-`UKSocket`-and-returns-an-`IAmericanSocket`.

The existence of another class would not make a difference, unless it were registered as an adapter.  If you register two adapters which might both be suitable their interactions are complicated, but since they both do the job, in theory you shouldn't care which one gets used.